# Server tag is not well formed error on datagrid row ImageButton

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datagrid, imagebutton

I have come to an issue like the server tag is not well. this code is ASP.NET C# code.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Options">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbuttEditVendor" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ctpv_id") %>" ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/edit.gif" />                
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ctpv_id") %>"
```

with

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ctpv_id") %>'
```

**Note**: Embed double quote in the double quote is not allowed.

Comment: Yes that is working perfectly Thanks @navylover

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it's helpful?

Comment: how to accept that answer? Ok will do it

Comment: Tick the number on the left of the question? I'm not sure^_^

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.